# why doesn't full screen wok on touchend?

Tags: javascript, html5-fullscreen

I'm trying to make a page go full screen as soon as the user starts scrolling on mobile.

I'm aware of the fact that as stated in this [mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) , for usability reasons, the browser will only allow a page to occupy the full-screen in response to a user gesture, therefore, I need to place my request to full-screen within a fast event handler so I did the following:

```js
function goFullScreen() {
  if (document.fullscreenEnabled) {
    requestFullscreen(document.documentElement);
  }
  document.removeEventListener('touchend', goFullScreen);
}

document.addEventListener('touchend', goFullScreen);
```

However, when I scroll the page I get this result on chrome:

[image]

I must be missing something here because when I click, without dragging the pointer, it does work.

**PS**: full version of the script can be found in this [fiddle] ..
 (https://jsfiddle.net/OsvaldoM/0kpm1s93/13/)
 also , this is just an experiment so please don't mind the terrible effects it would have to UX

Comment: This sounds like a terrible user experience

Comment: `for usability reasons`!! When the page certainly goes full screen while scrolling i would leave it immidiately.

Comment: Yeah I'd hate to scroll a website and see it fill my entire screen.

Comment: full screen mode can only be requested by a user gesture (an event like click). Scroll is not a user gesture.

Comment: thank you @StefanOctavian , I probably can't distinguish what is a user gesture from what is not(I was sure scroll events were) . so I replaced `scroll` with `touchend` but it behaves the same so it probably works only with events similar to click.